# Large View using Union ALL on Oracle 11gR2

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle

I'd like to create a view using Union ALL. The View itself will be fairly large.  Between 500 million and 800 million records.

That said, the underlying data will be partitioned 4 times per year and has the appropriate indexes.  The queries for the individual ranges themselves should have a fairly low cost.

Do I need to worry at all about the size of the view (in terms of the number of rows)?  Would I be better off using a separate table which consists of the data generated by the view and loading via an ETL process.  I am unfamiliar with how views operate internally, so my concern is if having say 30+ unions will be an issue.

Appreciate your Input.

Comment: "has the appropriate indexes" - If the indexes are on the columns most used in your access of the view then performance shouldn't be a problem. A view has no "size" in the database as it is merely a stored SQL statement, you're only real concern is how others will query the view and will they make use of the underlying indexes otherwise their queries could suffer performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is just an SQL statement that you "hide" away. So when you reference your view the SQL statement is run every time, so I would say it depends on how you will use the view. What predicates (where-clause) are you likely to use when using the view? If these predicates enables oracle to quickly eliminate lots of rows/join from the result then it will be fast.

You need to test it! Maybe using a materialized view could be an option? That would give you a table that is automatically maintained.

My first option would be to use and test the view at least, since you don't have to maintain it in any way. Using some type of ETL sounds like a bit of work:)